# Generate Dynamic couponcode every time in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, woocommerce, coupon

I am using this https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-coupon-programatically/ code to generate coupon code programmatically.

It's work good. But every time that generate **UNIQUECODE** same name code. I want to generate different code every time.

Example : UNIQUECODE12, UNIQUECODE14, UNIQUECODE16 etc.

So please help me how this possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a WordPress option using the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) that is a coupon counter. You can access and increment the counter every time you use it.

```
<?php
add_option( 'coupon-count', 0 ); // only sets it if it isn't in the database
$coupon_count = get_option( 'coupon-count' ); // access count
$coupon_count++; // increment the count
update_option( 'coupon-count', $coupon_count ); // store the incremented count for
$coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE' . '-' . $coupon_count; // Numbered Code
```

Comment: Above code generate coupon code like this -> http://nimb.ws/8s96uk

I want to add UNIQUECODE before that coupon code.

Comment: Looks like I have a + where you need a .

Comment: I just updated it. Glad to see the count is working.

Comment: Yes. It's working. but every time increment 1 number. How can i increment 3 number every time?

Example:  UNIQUECODE3, UNIQUECODE6, UNIQUECODE9,  UNIQUECODE12 etc.

Comment: Instead of $coupon_count++; you can use $coupon_count += 3;

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Good luck with the project